# SQLException: ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I'm working on an application that inserts queries into DB while performing some transactions. While running transactions I got this error:

> SQL Exception: ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition

The table is called `payment_transactions` and here is the partition data :

```
FEB15_3 26-SEP-16   4444    217 4444    TIMESTAMP' 2015-02-22 00:00:00'
SEP16_4 26-SEP-16   127554  5892    127554  TIMESTAMP' 2016-10-01 00:00:00'
JAN14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-01-15 00:00:00'
JAN14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-01-22 00:00:00'
FEB14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-02-15 00:00:00'
FEB14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-02-08 00:00:00'
MAR14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-03-15 00:00:00'
JAN14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-02-01 00:00:00'
MAR14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-03-08 00:00:00'
FEB14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-03-01 00:00:00'
FEB14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-02-22 00:00:00'
APR14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-04-08 00:00:00'
APR14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-04-15 00:00:00'
APR14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-04-22 00:00:00'
APR14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-05-01 00:00:00'
MAR14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-03-22 00:00:00'
MAR14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-04-01 00:00:00'
MAY14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-05-08 00:00:00'
MAY14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-05-15 00:00:00'
JUN14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-06-08 00:00:00'
MAY14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-06-01 00:00:00'
MAY14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-05-22 00:00:00'
JUN14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-06-22 00:00:00'
JUN14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-06-15 00:00:00'
JUL14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-07-08 00:00:00'
JUL14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-07-15 00:00:00'
JUN14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-07-01 00:00:00'
JUL14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-08-01 00:00:00'
JUL14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-07-22 00:00:00'
AUG14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-08-08 00:00:00'
AUG14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-08-22 00:00:00'
AUG14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-08-15 00:00:00'
AUG14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-09-01 00:00:00'
SEP14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-09-08 00:00:00'
SEP14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-10-01 00:00:00'
SEP14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-09-22 00:00:00'
SEP14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-09-15 00:00:00'
OCT14_1 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-10-08 00:00:00'
OCT14_3 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-10-22 00:00:00'
OCT14_2 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-10-15 00:00:00'
OCT14_4 26-SEP-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-11-01 00:00:00'
NOV14_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-11-08 00:00:00'
NOV14_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-11-15 00:00:00'
NOV14_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-11-22 00:00:00'
NOV14_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-12-01 00:00:00'
DEC14_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-12-08 00:00:00'
DEC14_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-12-15 00:00:00'
DEC14_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2014-12-22 00:00:00'
DEC14_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-01-01 00:00:00'
JAN15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-01-08 00:00:00'
JAN15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-01-15 00:00:00'
JAN15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-01-22 00:00:00'
JAN15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-02-01 00:00:00'
FEB15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-02-08 00:00:00'
FEB15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-02-15 00:00:00'
FEB15_3 26-Sep-16   4444    217 4444    TIMESTAMP' 2015-02-22 00:00:00'
FEB15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-03-01 00:00:00'
MAR15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-03-08 00:00:00'
MAR15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-03-15 00:00:00'
MAR15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-03-22 00:00:00'
MAR15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-04-01 00:00:00'
APR15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-04-08 00:00:00'
APR15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-04-15 00:00:00'
APR15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-04-22 00:00:00'
APR15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-05-01 00:00:00'
MAY15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-05-08 00:00:00'
MAY15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-05-15 00:00:00'
MAY15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-05-22 00:00:00'
MAY15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-06-01 00:00:00'
JUN15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-06-08 00:00:00'
JUN15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-06-15 00:00:00'
JUN15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-06-22 00:00:00'
JUN15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-07-01 00:00:00'
JUL15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-07-08 00:00:00'
JUL15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-07-15 00:00:00'
JUL15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-07-22 00:00:00'
JUL15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-08-01 00:00:00'
AUG15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-08-08 00:00:00'
AUG15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-08-15 00:00:00'
AUG15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-08-22 00:00:00'
AUG15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-09-01 00:00:00'
SEP15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-09-08 00:00:00'
SEP15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-09-15 00:00:00'
SEP15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-09-22 00:00:00'
SEP15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-10-01 00:00:00'
OCT15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-10-08 00:00:00'
OCT15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-10-15 00:00:00'
OCT15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-10-22 00:00:00'
OCT15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-11-01 00:00:00'
NOV15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-11-08 00:00:00'
NOV15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-11-15 00:00:00'
NOV15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-11-22 00:00:00'
NOV15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-12-01 00:00:00'
DEC15_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-12-08 00:00:00'
DEC15_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-12-15 00:00:00'
DEC15_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2015-12-22 00:00:00'
DEC15_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-01-01 00:00:00'
JAN16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-01-08 00:00:00'
JAN16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-01-15 00:00:00'
JAN16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-01-22 00:00:00'
JAN16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-02-01 00:00:00'
FEB16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-02-08 00:00:00'
FEB16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-02-15 00:00:00'
FEB16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-02-22 00:00:00'
FEB16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-03-01 00:00:00'
MAR16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-03-08 00:00:00'
MAR16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-03-15 00:00:00'
MAR16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-03-22 00:00:00'
MAR16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-04-01 00:00:00'
APR16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-04-08 00:00:00'
APR16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-04-15 00:00:00'
APR16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-04-22 00:00:00'
APR16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-05-01 00:00:00'
MAY16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-05-08 00:00:00'
MAY16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-05-15 00:00:00'
MAY16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-05-22 00:00:00'
MAY16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-06-01 00:00:00'
JUN16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-06-08 00:00:00'
JUN16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-06-15 00:00:00'
JUN16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-06-22 00:00:00'
JUN16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-07-01 00:00:00'
JUL16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-07-08 00:00:00'
JUL16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-07-15 00:00:00'
JUL16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-07-22 00:00:00'
JUL16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-08-01 00:00:00'
AUG16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-08-08 00:00:00'
AUG16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-08-15 00:00:00'
AUG16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-08-22 00:00:00'
AUG16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-09-01 00:00:00'
SEP16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-09-08 00:00:00'
SEP16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-09-15 00:00:00'
SEP16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-09-22 00:00:00'
SEP16_4 26-Sep-16   127554  5892    127554  TIMESTAMP' 2016-10-01 00:00:00'
OCT16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-10-08 00:00:00'
OCT16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-10-15 00:00:00'
OCT16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-10-22 00:00:00'
OCT16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-11-01 00:00:00'
NOV16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-11-08 00:00:00'
NOV16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-11-15 00:00:00'
NOV16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-11-22 00:00:00'
NOV16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-12-01 00:00:00'
DEC16_1 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-12-08 00:00:00'
DEC16_2 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-12-15 00:00:00'
DEC16_3 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2016-12-22 00:00:00'
DEC16_4 26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-01 00:00:00'
PARTITION_20170101  26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-02 00:00:00'
PARTITION_20170102  26-Sep-16   0   0       TIMESTAMP' 2017-01-03 00:00:00'
```

Comment: The error says that you're trying to insert a value for which no partition exists, because it's different from any value for which a partition exists, or it is null. You should check the data you need to insert and the partitions you have in the table.

Comment: What kind of data do you try to insert? Does the table use INTERVAL partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your table is partitioned into weekly chunks. This error ...

> "ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition"

... simply means that you are tying to insert a row with a partition key column value `>= TIMESTAMP '2017-01-03 00:00:00'`.

The solution is to ask your friendly DBA to create a new partition for the current month. Or see whether they might be prepared to move to the highly neat INTERVAL partitioning mechanism (although some DBAs are strongly attached to their partition naming schemes...). [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#BABIAAFH).

Comment: It looks rather like weekly chunks, not months.